# Can we create XRP account address with a given string pattern and complete the rest with the checksum?

Tags: javascript, cryptography, xrp

Can we create XRP account address with a given string pattern and complete the rest with the checksum?

For example:  If we want to create an XRP account address that includes a particular string pattern like "xxtomxxjerry". Can we find an approach to creating such an account address in any XRPL related javascript library?

Answer (score 2):

Account addresses in the XRP Ledger are `base58` encoded public-key representations.

The public-key is a valid point on the curve, sometimes inside a specific subgroup of the curve (when the curve isn't prime order).

XRP supports both `edwards25519` and `secp256k1` curves.

You reach the public point (which is deterministic but not predictable), by scalar multiplication of the curves generator (or subgroups generator) with a cryptographically secure random number which is approximately of the order `2^256`.

So to answer your question... in a tight loop you need to:

1. Generate a cryptographically secure random number between `0` and `2^256`.
2. Execute scalar multiplication of this random number by the appropriate group generator.
3. Take the resultant raw curve point and follow the XRP spec (including `base58` encoding), to reach the address value.
4. Inspect the generated address for desired vanity properties.
5. If target is reached, break and securely store the scalar.

Eventually you will find a specific address which matches your requirement. More than a few characters will take a long time, predicated of course on your hardware.